# Error: Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match

Tags: solidity, web3js, parity, mapping, query

I am `querying` a `mapping` via a `web3` `call` like this:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); 
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://kovan.infura.io/key...'));
var contractABI = new web3.eth.Contract([...abi...], contractAddress);
var orderValue = '15';
contractABI.methods.orders(web3.utils.toHex(orderValue)).call(function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            callback(result);
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
```

If `orderValue` is > 15 then I get the following error:

> Error: Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match.

If `orderValue` is <= 15 (e.g. 10) then I get the following error:

> throw new Error('Given parameter bytes has an invalid length: "'+
>   value + '"');
>
> Error: Given parameter bytes has an invalid length: "0xa"

the mapping in the smart contract looks as follows:

```
struct Order {
    bytes32 orderId;
    uint32 orderAmount;
}
mapping(bytes32 => Order) public orders;
```

If if query `orders` with `Parity` I am getting some values back. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try passing 0x0a

Comment: `0x0a` gives me the same error: `Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match.`

Comment: Just pass `orderValue` instead of `web3.utils.toHex(orderValue)`. That should clear up the "invalid length" errors. After that, you'll presumably get the "Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI" error for every `orderValue` you pass. This is most likely due to the ABI or contract address being wrong. You'd need to share the values you're using for someone to help investigate that.

Comment: If I just pass a `string` e.g. "test", I get: `Given parameter is not bytes: "test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is, **that the contract was deployed, but empty**!

Section 7.1 of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) it states that *"while the initialisation code is executing, the newly created address exists but with no intrinsic body code. For a normal STOP code, or if the code returned is otherwise empty, then the state is left with a zombie account, and any remaining balance will be locked into the account forever"* (Thanks to user Thomas Clowes)

The thing that was confusing me was that `Parity` could do queries on it, even though it returned `0x000` values (`web3` didn't return anything but errors). So I thought the contract wasn't empty!

Answer (score -1):

You're giving it bytes, (byte[]), not bytes32. It must be left padded with 0s for the contract to accept it.

Edit: Use `fromAscii` not `toHex`

fromAscii is string -> bytes

toHex is anything -> bytes

Comment: Still the same error: `Couldn't decode bytes32 from ABI: 0x The size doesn't match.`

Comment: Even after left-padding to have a 32 bytes element?